# import swift class into objective-C works, but some custom file not

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

My project has Objective-C file and Swift file (mix and match, thanks to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

Now, i add a new folder named 'Helper' on my project to contain function which i can use at any class.

Any swift class in my `Controller` folder is included in `my-project.swift.h`
and i can use it in any Objective-C class without any issue. But, here is the problem, i can't use swift class inside the `Helper` folder which i created by myself (it is outside `Controller` folder), so i can't use it on my objective-C class. Any solution here? Here is my helper file

```
import Foundation
public class imageHelper{
    func ResizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let size = image.size

    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height

    // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * heightRatio, size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * widthRatio,  size.height * widthRatio)
    }

    // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)

    // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.drawInRect(rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}

func imageWithSize(image: UIImage,size: CGSize)->UIImage{
    if UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector("scale"){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,false,UIScreen.mainScreen().scale);
    }
    else
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    }

    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}

//Summon this function VVV
func resizeImageWithAspect(image: UIImage,scaledToMaxWidth width:CGFloat,maxHeight height :CGFloat)->UIImage
{
    let oldWidth = image.size.width;
    let oldHeight = image.size.height;

    let scaleFactor = (oldWidth > oldHeight) ? width / oldWidth : height / oldHeight;

    let newHeight = oldHeight * scaleFactor;
    let newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;
    let newSize = CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight);

    return imageWithSize(image, size: newSize);
}
}
```

Comment: check your build phases -> compile sources, and make sure `imageHelper.swift` is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out!
just change this code

```
public class imageHelper{
```

into this

```
class imageHelper: NSObject{
```